# Firestore security rules check parent fields while calling child collections

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

So my firestore database is structured as such:

> documents -> collection -> docID -> collections -> documents

Inside the docID document I have a field called **live** which is a boolean set to either true or false. If live is true, I want to allow access to all documents and subdocuments, but if its false do not allow read. I've tried structuring it as such:

```
match /collections/{docID} {
    allow read: if resource.data.live == true;
    allow write: if false;
}
```

What is incorrect with this code?

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of your database in which one of the identities you mention is displayed? This will allow us to have a better undestanding of your database's structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
match /collection/{docID} {

  match /collections/{document=**} {
       allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/collection/$(docID)).data.live == true;
       allow write: if false;
  }

}
```

Here, document=** means all nested documents (of the same collection as well as nested).
And a simple get call to read your {docID} document.

You can find more info here [Access other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents)

Comment: would you care to clarify this answer? does it mean only IDs with that condition under the ID will be allowed? I have a similar situation where I have a users collection and a conversations one. I only want to allow users access to their own data except when they are part of a conversation - needed because user A posts an update to user B conversations information in current code base. If anyone can provide more clarity and details that is greatly appreciated, thank you.